# Is there a way to clean macOS IAP fetched products cache

Tags: macos, caching, in-app-purchase

I'm testing IAP in an application in bad network conditions using Network Link Conditioner. I'd like to test a case when products are not fetched yet. I enable 100% loss. Sometimes I'm lucky and `initWithProductIdentifiers` leads to `request:didFailWithError:`. But when I let it fetch products with enabled network I keep getting success with disabled network even after cleaning app folder in `~/Library/Containers/<app_id>`. It seems mac reboot helps to reset IAP cache. Maybe I can execute something in terminal without mac reboot?